Can the logic I want be completed using React's useMutation?
const myRequest = (req: ReqMyParam) => {
  return postFetchData<ResMyParam, ReqMyParam>(
    myRoutes.myApi,
    req,
  )
}
export const useMyApiMutation = (
  onSuccess: (res: ResSuccessMessage<ResMyParam>) => void,
  onError: (error: ResErrorMessage) => void,
) => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (req: ReqMyParam) => {
      return myRequest(req)
    },
    onSuccess: onSuccess,
    onError: onError,
  })
}

This is the source code for useMutation that I wrote.
myRequest(
        {
          orderId: DATA.trxUnqNo,
          totAmt: trxAmt,
        },
        {// How can I add that part to myRequest?
          rpsCd,
          rpsMsg,
          trxSno,
        },
      )

  const { mutate: myRequest} = useMyApiMutation(
    ({ DATA }: ResSuccessMessage<ResMyParam>) => {
      const url = DATA.checkoutPage
      otherMutation({
        // This is to use additional parameters when calling other APIs.
        rpsCd: rpsCd,
        rpsMsg: rpsMsg,
        trxSno: trxSno,
        trxUnqNo: '',
        trxUnqKey: DATA.payToken,
      })
    },
    ({ MESSAGE }: ResErrorMessage) => {
      alert(MESSAGE)
    },
  )

The reason why I want to use it like this is because I want to change the then syntax using promise that I was using to mutation.
I'm still unfamiliar with how to use it, so even though I've searched a lot, it doesn't seem to work the way I'm trying. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if it's impossible.

React doesn't have a useMutation hook.  It looks like you're using tanstack query.
